# Testing an Airflow DAG end-to-end wtih fixed input from within a python unit test while mocking Configuration

Tags: python, unit-testing, airflow

So, I have a DAG and some specified input, and i expect a certain output. I want to run all operators end to end.

Currently I'm trying to write some unit test in python that will mock over the some configuration,
and then I also want to overwrite some input parameters in `dag_run.conf`.
This seems to be cumbersome, since i did not find a way yet to both mock `Variables.get`, `BaseHook.get_connection` and trigger a dag in the python unit test.

If I use `from airflow.api.client.local_client import Client` then I cannot mock over `Variable.get` and `Hook`s.

How would i best do that?

Is there some further documentation on how Airflow works internally (I'm suspecting it starts different processes that overwrite the mocks?)
Or maybe I'm just not doing this the way it was intended to be done?